# Maximum arena reward, stop after 9 wins?

Tags: hearthstone

Everytime I play the arena, I wonder how good the rewards can be and when you should stop playing the arena and claim your rewards.

**Does the reward for winning in the arena become any better after you get the top tier master key after 9 wins?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Note**: This answer is now outdated, as the December 12th, 2013 patch increased the number of reward levels to 12.

---

The arena is concluded once you get to 9 wins (or 3 losses / retire).

What is a "better" reward is personal preference.

If you mostly are after gold, then it is best to retire at 8 rather than 9. This is because you get more gold stacks (4 instead 3) as reward at 8 than 9.
If you want card packs, dust or a gold card, it is best to win 9.

Obviously this is all subject to change as the game is still only in beta and a number of people have brought up this issue with Blizzard.

These two topics on the Hearthstone forums explain the current issue regarding rewards quite well:

- [9 wins better than 8](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/10344274345)
- [Arena 8 wins > 9 wins](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/10432823266)